# how to fix error in google sheet "cant write formula"

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet

Hello so i just interfere with some problems in spreadsheet, i see this problem a lot from my co-workers so the error is i can't do some formula in spreadsheet but when i tried in a different sheet it work perfectly, in this case i only do some basic if function and you can see by click this link below:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yLZridIhibBQJke4W9hTY685chdGpVkL6ecu4wrnuZY/edit?usp=sharing
i put the formula in A2.

and this is the other sheet that work:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1h6LzFKfYgfBct-qc1BcozcOY6vDhEmvvwAAdudpks0o/edit?usp=sharing

so the question is, is there any formatting or cell problem in the first sheet? or maybe spreadsheet sometimes just error like this?

thanks in advance!

Comment: Problem is in you `Locale` settings. It was `Indonesia`  while other sheet was `United Kingdom`.